# Hash set add and search functions don't work properly - c++

Tags: c++, hash, set

I'm trying to implement a hash set. But it seems that the search function and the add function don't work properly. The add function lets me add a Person(which has phoneNumber and name) but when two Persons are in collision, something's not going well. The collisions are solved through separate chaining and the Persons are added at the end of the linked lists. I made some tests using assertions on the search function. If the element exists in the set, there's no problem but if it doesn't exist, then the assertions fails. Here's my code:

```
#ifndef SET_H_
#define SET_H_

//#include "Person.h"

class Set{
private:
    class Node{
        private:
            Person info;
            Node* next;
        public:
            Node(){
                this->next=NULL;
            }
            Node(Person info, Node* next){
                this->info=info;
                this->next=next;
            }
            Node(const Node& node){
                this->info=node.info;
                this->next=node.next;
            }
            ~Node(){}
            Person getInfo(){
                return this->info;
            }
            Node* getNext(){
                return this->next;
            }
            void setNext(Node* value){
                this->next=value;
            }
            void setInfo(Person el){
                this->info=el;
            }
        };
    Node** head;
    int size;
    int* bucketsize;
    int totalElements;
public:
    Set();
    ~Set();
    int hashFunction(long long int);
    bool isEmptyAtIndex(int index);
    bool isEmpty();
    bool search(Person e);
    void add(Person e);

    int totalElementsInTheSet(){
        return this->totalElements;
    }
    int HashSize(){
        return this->size;
    }
    int bucketNumberOfElements(int index){
        return this->bucketsize[index];
    }
};

Set::Set(){
    this->size=11;
    this->head = new Set::Node*[this->size];
    this->bucketsize= new int[this->size];
    for(int i=0; i < this->size; i++){
        this->head[i]=NULL;
        this->bucketsize[i]=0;
    }
    totalElements = 0;
}

Set::~Set(){
    delete[] head;
    delete[] bucketsize;
}


int Set::hashFunction(long long int nr){
    int sum=0;
    int divisor=10;
    while(nr != 0){
        sum+=nr % divisor;
        nr=nr / divisor;
    }
    int hashCode = sum % size;
    return hashCode;
}

bool Set::isEmpty(){
    if(totalElements==0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Set::add(Person p){
    if(search(p)==false){
        int index = hashFunction(p.getPhoneNumber());
        Node* addNode = new Set::Node(p,NULL);
        if(head[index]==NULL){
            head[index]=addNode;
            ++totalElements;
            ++bucketsize[index];
        }
        else{
            Node* cursor = head[index];
            while(cursor != NULL){
                cursor = cursor->getNext();
            }
            addNode->setNext(cursor->getNext());
            cursor->setNext(addNode);
            ++totalElements;
            ++bucketsize[index];
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"There's already a person with the given phone number!";
    }

}

bool Set::search(Person p){
    int index = hashFunction(p.getPhoneNumber());
    if(head[index]==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        Node* cursor = head[index];
        while((cursor->getInfo().getPhoneNumber() != p.getPhoneNumber()) and cursor != NULL){
            cursor = cursor->getNext();
        }
        if(cursor->getInfo().getPhoneNumber()== p.getPhoneNumber()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

#endif /* SET_H_ */
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to use this-> to access members in a method.

Comment: @brianbeuning I don't get it. I used -> where I could

Comment: @MonsterMonster He's referring to `this->` in your constructor.  There's no need for `this->`.

Comment: @CareyGregory Do you know why my functions aren't working as they should?

Comment: @MonsterMonster Instead of Node() { this->next = NULL } use Node() { next = NULL; }.  Same applies to all your Node and Set methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
Node* cursor = head[index];
while (cursor != NULL)
{
    cursor = cursor->getNext();
}
addNode->setNext(cursor->getNext());
```

When you exit the while loop, `cursor` is null.  Therefore, `cursor->getNext()` will produce an access violation.

Comment: CareyGregory I want to add at the end of the linked list so it should be while(cursor->getNext() != NULL) ?

Comment: Close.  It should be `while ((cursor = cursor->GetNext()) != NULL);`.

Comment: CareyGregory my assertions still fails. `Person* p3 = new Person("Bloody Mary",1232567);//4` and `Person* p = new Person("Razvan",725912976); //4`. If I do `set->add(*p);` everything fails and it appears a window for closing the application.

Comment: CareyGregory, I am testing the code using assertions #include <assert.h>

Comment: I understand that, but I don't know what assertion is failing.  Please show the assertions in your code.

Comment: CareyGregory, now evertyhing works. I changed the cursor->getNext() != NULL in the search function too. Thanks for you answers.